# Javascript: Get symbol unicode from Font Awesome

Tags: javascript, unicode, font-awesome

Lets say I have camera-retro icon with unicode: '\uf083'. Now camera-retro icon in FontAwesome has unicode of '\f083'. How would I get the original unicode of camera-retro icon from FontAwesome icon?

Here is the example that shows generating SVG element with font-awesome. As you can see it only works with original unicode. That's why I need to get the original unicode, not the font-awesome one
[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/zusehowave/edit?html,js,output)

I am able to get the FontAwesome unicode with this function:

```
function faUnicode(name) {
    var testI = document.createElement('i');
    var char;

    testI.className = 'fa ' + name;
    document.body.appendChild(testI);

    char = window.getComputedStyle( testI, ':before' )
        .content.replace(/'|"/g, '');

    testI.remove();
    return char.charCodeAt(0);
}
```

But as I said, I need to get the original unicode of that icon. Any ideas?
Basically in return I want String like '\uf083';

Answer (score 2):

replace the last line with:
`return "\\u" + char.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)`

Comment: Thanks, it seems to convert fine. But I have one more problem. When I set my object like text: '\uf1de'}  it works, but when I set it like text: faUnicode('fa-icon');  it doesn't display the icon but the String \uf1de.

Comment: sorry, I don't understand your use-case, can you perhaps post a fiddle with the code in question?